# Chat system implementation

Tags: javascript, ajax, nginx, chat, comet

I am required to implement a live chat system, somewhat similar to Facebook's in that it must:

- Allow communication between 2 users
- Store messages in an inbox/sent box
- Store messages in inbox, marked unread if the user is offline when a message is sent
- A language/spam filter must also be active, as needs to monitor communication involving minors.
- Ideally, this will work on most devices/browsers including mobile access.

I pretty much have a blank canvas for this project in terms of what OS/software to use.

Having done a bit of research it seems like there's a few options / things to think about?

- PHP/AJAX long polling (Comet-style) with a standard LAMP stack storing messages in a mysql DB
- LEMP stack (nginx)using the HTTP Push Module, again Comet-style server with a php backend storing messages in a mysql DB
- Node.js?
- HTML5 interface to maintain browser/device support?
- Best DB system for this? Some people suggested mongoDB?
- Some people also suggested utilising MemCacheQ to boost performance.

What are your thoughts this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Concerning Chats, i am a friend of WebSockets.

Comment: I did notice a few suggestions of websockets, but they didn't seem as popular. What do you see as the benefits?

Comment: @swiss196 It's a new technology (not supported in all browsers) that allows for continuous bi-directional communication, without polling/waiting

Comment: By the looks of things, it's not supported at all by Android so I guess I'd need to provide a fallback method? They look cool and the modern way to go but just don't think I'd have the time to code 2 methods...

Comment: Comet is a solution: communicating real time data over HTTP. The Websocket protocol does fit into this Comet paradigm, but can also solves other problems not applicable to Comet. WebSockets have their own security layer, and follow different rules. (http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/websockets-or-comet-or-both-whats-supported-in-the-java-ee-land/)

Comment: @Gary How easy would it be to create a solution using WebSockets that falls back to ajax long polling on unsupported browsers, e.g android browser?

Comment: Hm, i dont know because it never was a question for me... You can use WS in all WebKit-Browsers (Safari, Chrome), in IE 10+, Opera 10.7+, FF 4+... Isnt that enough?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd like mobile support as well. Although perhaps we don't permit 'live' chat over mobile devices using websockets but just allow messages to be sent between inboxes - that should work I think!

Comment: hmmm @swiss196 Are you really in Swiss? I'm in Lausanne, and we could help eachother out. I'm doing almost the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately not, but would still be interested in working with you? What's the best way to get in touch?

Answer (score 2):

Check out SignalR as the way of passing the messages between clients, it's the easiest way to create a chat application.

Comment: By the looks of things this use WebSockets as Gary commented above but looks to for .NET? Have you had experience with this before? What makes it so easy?

Comment: @swiss196 I think it's only for .NET, but it is a wrapper library for Web Sockets, so that you don't have to right a lot of low level code. It's an accepted, easy library that makes it easy to use Web Sockets

Comment: I have used SignalR to develop two player board games, google SignalR and look at some of the videos created by the developers, you will have a basic chat app in minutes, websockets are difficult to programme.

Comment: Looks like I can run SignalR in Mono on a linux box - maybe this is an option after all!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the sort of thing that the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express.js, Angular.js, Node.js) combined with either socket.io, or lightstreamer would be good at.  Lightstreamer is supposedly faster and more scalable than socket.io (and their live demo's don't make me doubt that), it also has a page in their documentation discussing PhoneGap (they handle phones that don't support WebSockets...which is useful, because, as I understand it, WebSockets aren't supported by most phones)

This isn't my area of expertise though, but it may be worth researching.